# ? qualifier в regex (python 3.5)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Занимаюсь парсингом текстов судебных решений. Есть такой кусок текста, из которого нужно вытащить информацию о наказании (лишении свободы):
`в виде лишения свободы на срок 3 года 10 месяцев со штрафом в размере 150 000 рублей с ограничением свободы на срок на 8 месяцев.`

Составленный regex
`лишени[а-я]+\s*?свободы\s*?на\s*?(?:срок)?\s*?(?:(?P<years>\d+).*?(?:года?|лет)?)?\s*?и?\s*?(?:(?P<months>\d+)\s*?(?:месяц[а-я]{0,3}))?`
даёт результат `лишения свободы на`, однако если убрать заключительный знак вопроса (который убирать в общем случае нельзя), то получается нужный результат:
`лишения свободы на срок 3 года 10 месяцев`.
В [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) сказано:

> The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible.

Вопрос: почему в моём случае добавление `?` даёт обратный (не тот, что мною ожидается) эффект?

Comment: А почему после лет `.*?`? Почему не `\s*`? В общем, у меня пока получилось только https://regex101.com/r/4ls28x/2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `.*?` из-за таких случаев: `...лишения свободы на 5 (пять) лет...`

Comment: Тогда  так - https://regex101.com/r/4ls28x/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо! Попробовал первый вариант, подставив `.*?`  - почему в данном случае он матчит ноль символов, а не до первого продолжения шаблона (в чём как раз и должна проявляться "нежадность")? Из-за стоящего после `лет` `?` он даже не смотрит, есть ли в строке возможное продолжение? Потому что такое работает - https://regex101.com/r/4ls28x/4

Comment: В общем, проблема в том, что после `.*?` должен быть хотя бы один обязательный шаблон. В оригинальном выражении все они необязательные, так как после каждого из них стоит квантификатор `?`. Т.е. `год` или `лет` точно должны быть, да?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо за разъяснение! :) `год` или `лет` вообще должны быть, да, добавил `?` для страховки от опечаток типа `грда`. Если хотите, добавьте ваш последний коммент как ответ, я отмечу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что после `.*?` должен быть хотя бы один обязательный шаблон. В оригинальном выражении все они необязательные, так как после каждого из них стоит квантификатор `?` - один или ноль совпадений.

Так как `год` или `лет` точно должны быть в искомом тексте, можно использовать

```
лишени[а-я]+\s*свободы\s*на(?:\s*срок)?(?:\s*(?:(?P<years>\d+).*?(?:года?|лет)))?(?:\s*и)?(?:\s*(?P<months>\d+)(?:\s*месяц[а-я]{0,3}))?
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/4ls28x/4)

Теперь `(?:года?|лет)` обязтельный шаблон, и `.*?` должен будет "дойти" до одного из этих вариантов. В противном случае, `.*?` пропускается, остальные находят пустую строку (так как они необязательные), и подстрока после лет не находится. Кстати, все остальные квантификаторы должны быть "жадными".